# Yii1: Controller::beforeRender in Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I'm migrating an old app developed in Yii1 to Yii2.

I used to have a array in the controller that was storing all the variables that I would need to send to the frontend as a JavaScript:

```
public $jsVars;
public function toJSObject($params){
    $this->jsVars = array_merge($this->jsVars, $params);
}

private function printJSVarsObject(){
  //convert my php array into a js json object
}
```

When I needed a variable to be exposed in Javascript, I would just use $this->toJSObject, in the View or in the Controller.

Then, in the controller I also used to have:

```
public function beforeRender($view){
  $this->printJSVarsObject();
}
```

In Yii2, I had to configure the View component with a custom View and then attach an event:

```
namespace app\classes;

use yii\base\Event;
use yii\helpers\Json;

Event::on(\yii\web\View::className(), \yii\web\View::EVENT_END_BODY, function($event) {
    $event->sender->registerJSVars();
});

class View extends \yii\web\View {
    public $jsVars = [];

    public function addJsParam($param){
        $this->jsVars = array_merge($this->jsVars, $param);
    }

    public function registerJSVars() {
        $this->registerJs(
            "var AppOptions= " . Json::htmlEncode($this->jsVars) . ";",
            View::POS_END,
            'acn_options'
        );
    }
}
```

But, having the event outside the class seems weird to me. Also, while I'm in the controller, I won't be able to use my former approach using this method.

Obviously, I'm missing something, or my approach is just incorrect.

How do you guys do that?

Comment: The `beforeRender()` method has moved to the view in Yii2, so you can just override that each time you need it in your controller, for example; `\Yii::$app->view->on(View::EVENT_END_BODY, function () {
    echo date('Y-m-d');
});` If you have more complex code and want to keep it DRY then just attach it as a behaviour of the controller

Comment: Or, if you're just trying to access properties of the controller from your view, you can use `$this->context` to access the controller

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm doing sometimes, I was just looking for the "perfect" approach. Please answer again with the $this->context answer so I can accept it ;) thanks for your time dude

Comment: :-) no worries. My gf plays candy crush, I answer questions on SE. Go figure :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to access properties of the controller from a view (see above comments!), you can use;

```
$this->context
```

to return an instance of the currently used controller from within the view file. So to access your `beforeRender()` method you would just use

```
$this->context->beforeRender()
```